# how to keep the user logged until user log out himself?

Tags: php, session, cookies, authentication

I have php login page that stores the user id in the session once the login is successful. User can navigate to different pages or can even close the page briefly and once user re-open the page, he is still logged in. However the problem is that when the user closes the page for longer time, the session get expired automatically and he has to re-enter the credentials and login again.

How can I keep the user logged in forever and log out ONLY if user decides to do so?
I would like the user to be able to close the page, turn off the pc for weeks and when he or she comes back to visit the page, he or she should be already logged in.

Comment: either cookies or set the session to never expire

Answer (score 1):

Sound like you need to set the cookie expiration date - as per [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Expires_and_Max-Age) on HTTP cookies, if you do not set an expiration date for a cookie it becomes a session cookie. i.e. it expires once the browser closes.

There is no real way to specify that a cookie NEVER expires, however you can set the expiration date for some time far in the future.. i.e. in 10 years, and renew that expiration date every time the user loads a page.

```
setCookie( name, value, expiration )
```

Another alternative (which would also require some JS on your pages) would be to use the browser's internal database to store the user session id so that you can retrieve the session from your database (I assume you are using some sort of database, otherwise you will run into other issues as explained below).

If I wanted to achieve this I would probably have a piece of javascript on my page loads that checked for the existence of the session cookie, and if not, I would load the session id from the browser's database, drop the cookie, and force a page reload. There are certainly more elegant ways of achieving this, but this should give you an example of how to get this started.

Lastly, please keep in mind that if you don't use a database (i.e. Redis, Memcached, SQL), all you session information is lost when you restart your application server. This is certainly suboptimal, and you should store session information in a database if you want to have this information survive server restarts (or if you have a load balanced environment).

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the reply. It is still not clear for me. I am not using cookies at all! So should I create a cookie and store the session ID inside it and use the session ID from the cookie the next time to retrieve the details from the server?

Comment: So the problem here is that there needs to be away for you to identify a session, and typically this is done by attaching a "session id" to every request made from the client (browser) to the server. The easiest way to accomplish this is by dropping a cookie on the client's machine with that id, so that you can link all subsequent requests to the a specific session. What is your concern with using cookies?

Comment: Problem with this is that the new apache server destroys the session after 24minutes. The solution was to generate a random hashed token and stores it in the database and use that token to authenticate the session was destroyed by the server.